# Renovated basement room, added outlets to circuit, now Dishwasher voltage is too low, separate circuit

Tags: electrical, remodeling

I renovated a room in my basement, adding ceiling lights and outlets onto an existing circuit in the room.  The lights are LED, not too bright.  My dishwasher started having issues, error code reads voltage is too low.  The dishwasher is on a separate breaker, it's the only thing on that line as far as I know.  If I switch off the breaker to the room I worked on, the dishwasher works correctly and will run the whole cycle.  The room I worked on is below the dishwasher.  What should I be looking for at this point?
Thank you

Comment: Seems like a problem with the new circuit.  A loose connection, damage wire insulation.  Will need to check all your work, plus maybe the wires/cables.  Hopefully the problem is easy to find, but might need to look very close for minor damage.  Would use a multi-meter to confirm low voltage.

Comment: Are the 2 circuits wired as a "multi-wire branch circuit" sharing a neutral wire?  The circuit you added stuff to, does it serve general-use receptacles in the kitchen?   How did you wire the lights?

Comment: It sounds like they are sharing a bad neutral which could be a bad or loose connection. This is assuming no other circuits in your home are affected.

Comment: Low voltage causes are loose connection or contaminated Neutral. To test, **temporary** disconnect the neutral in the basement circuits.

Comment: "If I switch off the breaker to the room I worked on, the dishwasher works correctly [on a separate breaker] and will run the whole cycle." ... IDK, +1. Are those switches, three-way?

Comment: I pulled my dishwasher out and found inside the junction box was melting where the neutral was connected.  I purchased another and installed, works well.  This was also the odd smell that my wife was noticing recently. I don't know if this was caused by the renovation wiring, or it was coincidental.  I went through and rechecked my work, got out a multi meter and everything was around 119v.  I'll keep an eye on everything, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @GregoryBrouillette -- post that as your answer and I'll +1 it